# ajax error when connect to php class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm new to php and ajax and i have error 
uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier
i don't know where is the problem me ajax code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
            console.log( "it's working" );
                var data = (id);
                alert (data);
               // $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "push.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "myid=" data,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `data: "myid=" data` needs to be `data: "myid=" + data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
data: "myid=" data,
```

Should be

```
data: "myid=" + data,
```

The "+" operator concatenates the two strings together.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem indeed

Answer (score 2):

Or simply data: {myid: data},

Also, you may want to show the console.log in the success part to ensure the ajax request is complete.